# prevent QTreeView item from auto collapsing after filtering out

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtreeview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I'm implementing an incremental search field for a QTreeView using QSortFilterProxyModel. The search field is a QLineEdit as follows:

```
self.ui_search_lineedit.textEdited[unicode].connect(self._onSearchEdited)
```

and my _onSearchEdited function looks like:

```
def _onSearchEdited(self, text):
    self.proxy_model.setFilterFixedString(text)
    self.ui_treeview.clearSelection()
```

However, If I expand an item in the tree view and do a search, if the item doesn't match, it will disappear. When I delete my search keyword to make it match the item, the item will show up again, but it is collapsed. For example, if my item is "410" and I have expanded it; I type "4100" in the search field, the item will be hidden; but if I delete one 0 to make the search key "410", the item will show up but it is collapsed.

Is there any way to make the item remain expanded unless the user manually collapse it?

Answer (score 0):

You could manually check and store every item collapse state and then return it to the desired state.

Comment: Where? How? Example?